# Html css javascript preloader code, I have a code below, why does the javascript are not able to reload

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Below are my javascript code, why the preloader doesnt show up when I refresh? The first code i use to append a new preloader inside it when it start running javascript, does anyone know how I can append a things that used to replace another thing at the bottom there, as well as three screw driver is running around the place and here.

```
$('body').append('<div id="loader-background"><div class="load"><div class="gear one"><svg id="blue" viewbox="0 0 100 100" fill="#aeb2b7"><path d="M97.6,55.7V44.3l-13.6-2.9c-0.8-3.3-2.1-6.4-3.9-9.3l7.6-11.7l-8-8L67.9,20c-2.9-1.7-6-3.1-9.3-3.9L55.7,2.4H44.3l-2.9,13.6      c-3.3,0.8-6.4,2.1-9.3,3.9l-11.7-7.6l-8,8L20,32.1c-1.7,2.9-3.1,6-3.9,9.3L2.4,44.3v11.4l13.6,2.9c0.8,3.3,2.1,6.4,3.9,9.3      l-7.6,11.7l8,8L32.1,80c2.9,1.7,6,3.1,9.3,3.9l2.9,13.6h11.4l2.9-13.6c3.3-0.8,6.4-2.1,9.3-3.9l11.7,7.6l8-8L80,67.9      c1.7-2.9,3.1-6,3.9-9.3L97.6,55.7z M50,65.6c-8.7,0-15.6-7-15.6-15.6s7-15.6,15.6-15.6s15.6,7,15.6,15.6S58.7,65.6,50,65.6z"></path></svg></div><div class="gear two"><svg id="pink" viewbox="0 0 100 100" fill="#ff6c60"><path d="M97.6,55.7V44.3l-13.6-2.9c-0.8-3.3-2.1-6.4-3.9-9.3l7.6-11.7l-8-8L67.9,20c-2.9-1.7-6-3.1-9.3-3.9L55.7,2.4H44.3l-2.9,13.6      c-3.3,0.8-6.4,2.1-9.3,3.9l-11.7-7.6l-8,8L20,32.1c-1.7,2.9-3.1,6-3.9,9.3L2.4,44.3v11.4l13.6,2.9c0.8,3.3,2.1,6.4,3.9,9.3      l-7.6,11.7l8,8L32.1,80c2.9,1.7,6,3.1,9.3,3.9l2.9,13.6h11.4l2.9-13.6c3.3-0.8,6.4-2.1,9.3-3.9l11.7,7.6l8-8L80,67.9      c1.7-2.9,3.1-6,3.9-9.3L97.6,55.7z M50,65.6c-8.7,0-15.6-7-15.6-15.6s7-15.6,15.6-15.6s15.6,7,15.6,15.6S58.7,65.6,50,65.6z"></path></svg></div><div class="gear three"><svg id="yellow" viewbox="0 0 100 100" fill="#36404e"><path d="M97.6,55.7V44.3l-13.6-2.9c-0.8-3.3-2.1-6.4-3.9-9.3l7.6-11.7l-8-8L67.9,20c-2.9-1.7-6-3.1-9.3-3.9L55.7,2.4H44.3l-2.9,13.6      c-3.3,0.8-6.4,2.1-9.3,3.9l-11.7-7.6l-8,8L20,32.1c-1.7,2.9-3.1,6-3.9,9.3L2.4,44.3v11.4l13.6,2.9c0.8,3.3,2.1,6.4,3.9,9.3      l-7.6,11.7l8,8L32.1,80c2.9,1.7,6,3.1,9.3,3.9l2.9,13.6h11.4l2.9-13.6c3.3-0.8,6.4-2.1,9.3-3.9l11.7,7.6l8-8L80,67.9      c1.7-2.9,3.1-6,3.9-9.3L97.6,55.7z M50,65.6c-8.7,0-15.6-7-15.6-15.6s7-15.6,15.6-15.6s15.6,7,15.6,15.6S58.7,65.6,50,65.6z"></path></svg></div></div><div class="text">loading</div></div>');
$(window).on('load', function(){
  setTimeout(removeLoader, 2000); //wait for page load PLUS two seconds.
});
```

Here is my CSS code which i use to style the preloader for my web page using vannila js. The css below show all the color correctly and other details

```
#loader-background {
    position:absolute;;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #f1f2f7;
    z-index: 5;
}

.load {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.gear {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 15;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  animation: spin 5s infinite;
}

.two {
  left: 40px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  animation: spin-reverse 5s infinite;
}

.three {
  top: 45px;
  left: -10px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}

@keyframes spin {
  50% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin-reverse {
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}

.lil-circle {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 2px gray, 0 0 50px white;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: .65;
}

.blur-circle {
    z-index: 20;
  position: absolute;
  top: -19px;
  left: -19px;
}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
```

Comment: The three gears are showing correctly for me. Is jQuery included correctly in your html? Can you post your html code? Also, what does "append a things that used to replace another thing at the bottom there, as well as three screw driver is running around the place and here" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="loader">preloader</h1>
    <script>
      window.onload = () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          document.querySelector('.loader').remove()
        }, 1000)
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

what i would do and recommend is not to add the preloader by Js, instead write it statically like i did in the example above.

**EDIT:**

To replace it with other content after preloader time expires, you can do is wrap the preloader in a div and in JS when page's loaded change its content with `innerHTML`:

```
<div class='loader'>
 <h1>Loading...</h1>
</div>
```

```
window.onload = () => {
 setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector('.loader').innerHTML = '<h1>Your content</h1>'
 }, 1000)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have defined the `removeLoader` function. It seems to be working with it as I did in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0cvw69r2/4/).